# How to focus in and out textarea with JQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/*$('textarea').focus(function() {
alert('IN!');
});*/

/*$('.mensagem').focusout(function() {
    alert('OUT!');
});*/

/*$('textarea').blur(function(){
    alert('OUT!');
});*/

/*$('textarea').on('focusout',function(){
alert('OUT!');
});

$('textarea').on('focus',function(){
alert('IN!');
});*/

$('textarea').focus(function() {
alert('IN!');
}).blur(function() {
alert('OUT!');
});

});
```

What happens when I enter textarea is that it first alerts "OUT!" and then "IN!".

EDIT:

I looks that the alert was a bad idea to make this test...

```
$('textarea').bind('focus', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color':'#E18B6B'
    });
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color':'#990012'
    });
});
```

Now I can see it is working. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Did you include jQuery and use document ready ?

Comment: Sorry, @adeneo, I edited the question to make myself clearer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qpxDk/

Comment: Are you entering your textarea from another textarea?

Comment: No, I am clicking on it.